# Comparing a VARCHAR2 to SYSDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, varchar

I have an `Oracle` column `END_DATE` that's a `varchar2(256)`. I need to compare that value to the `SYSDATE` but I keep getting errors.

```
END_DATE        |SYSDATE   
----------------|-------
06/30/2016 00:00|29-FEB-16
```

This is what I've tried:

```
u.END_DATE > SYSDATE ---> ORA-01843: not a valid month
TO_DATE(u.END_DATE, 'DD-MM-YY') > SYSDATE ----> ORA-01843: not a valid month
TO_DATE(u.END_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM') > SYSDATE ----> ORA-01810: format code appears twice
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: `to_date(u.end_date,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')` I believe

Comment: Now you know why you should **never** store dates as varchar values!

Comment: Well, you can't do maths with text. Does `END_DATE` contain strings in the same format or it's free input?

Comment: Your hours are military so we need to adjust to HH24:MI `to_date(u.end_date,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')`  to convert the varchar to a date which then can be compared to other dates. `Select  case when to_date('06/30/2016 00:00','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') > sysdate then 1 else 0 end as Compare_Date from dual;` for example.  This assumes end_Date is in a constant format as @ÁlvaroGonzález described.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The third attempt you have tried is almost it.

The `HH:MM` portion is wrong:

- MI (Minutes) should be used instead of MM (Month)
- HH24 should be used instead of HH

cf [Datetime Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm#CDEHIFJA).

This one should work:

```
TO_DATE(u.END_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') > SYSDATE
```